# Finding file size to decide on size cutoff for loading?

Tags: c#, filesize

I am writing a 32 bit app and so only 4GB, the files I process can be very huge upto 3.5 GB, but what size should I consider before loading the file for processing?

I mean, C# .net I suppose only have limited RAM for framework, what should be the cutoff for a file (though it depends on how much memory the application takes, just to arrive at a ballpark figure) ?  ( i dont have a file of that magnitude, just want to handle it before a memory error)

I suppose, what I need is `actual file size` than `file size on disk` ? and is it possible find that without opening the file?

Comment: FileInfo class will give you all the information you need about a file (not, it's not size on disk because it depends on file system and you shouldn't care about it for processing). That said you don't load whole file on memory so even a 32 bit application can handle 100 GB files...

Comment: @Adriano, thanks.. in the past we had issues with image files hitting peak when processing and sometimes the peak is larger than RAM size and we had memory error. It was a particular issue with GDI+ on servers -- somesort of memory leak with the gdi calls

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property.

But instead consider using stream classes (see [*Reader classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in System.IO), they allow you to read parts of a file, analyse it and discard. In this way you don't care about the size of a file at all.